# Retrieving MEDIUMBLOB from MySQL with PHP and PDO fails

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo, blob

I store image data in MEDIUMBLOB column of a images table which looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have `images.php` script which receives `id` of an image to display, calls an API which should receive image `id` paramater(amongst other things not relevant to this problem) and return binary string from `image` column to the `images.php` script which should display it.

This is the part of the API(actually a imageController) that fetches image data from db, loads it to my `Image` class, which determines image type based on first few byte signature and returns correspondent mime-type.

```
        $pdo = Database::getPDO($db);
        $select_image_statement = $pdo->prepare(
            "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = :id"
        );
        $select_image_statement->bindParam(":id", $image_id);
        $select_image_statement->execute();

        $select_image_statement->bindColumn(1, $img, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

        $select_image_statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

        $image = new Image();
        $image->load($img);

        $return = array(
            'image' => $img,
            'mime_type' => $image->getMimeType()
        );

        return $return;
```

The problem although is that `$img` bound variable always contains `˙Ř˙ŕ` sequence when I output it using `error_log($img)` and when i `echo` from my `image.php` script(without `header()`) I get blank page, also `empty()` returns 1 so i guess that `˙Ř˙ŕ` sequence is just some strange(at least to me) behavior of error_log when given empty input string.

Returning `empty($img)` or `isset($img)` or `count($img)` directly from API to the `image.php` and outputing it there all work consistently so there probably isn't some error when transfering image data.

I'm fetching row with no other problems or errors(other columns work as intended).

Also, when I click on the BLOB column from phpMyAdmin it shows stored image with no problem or errors so images are stored corectly and the only problem might be when retrieving it from db.
I also checked max allowed packet in MySQL config and it is set to 16,777,216 which should be enough as my images are maximum of 5 MB in size(the ones I'm trying to retrieve are ~100 kB)

I spent last ~6 hours trying to fix it and browsing SO similar question, reading PHP documentation and user comments for every PDO method i use and I tried all of the suggested ways of bounding columns, different fetching options and so on but none of it solved my problem. I tried doing it this way http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php#96311 and "official" way http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php (using streams) but both don't work in my case and in both cases `$img` is empty. 
I also tried connecting like this, as suggested in similar question here at SO

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$db['host']};dbname={$db['name']}", $db['user'], $db['password'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

and without `SET NAMES` command which both don't do nothing regarding my problem.

I'm desperate, I don't know what to do anymore and it's very late night here so I'm going to sleep now and I sincerely hope that i will dream a solution or at least some of you will know what's wrong and write it up for me or share a useful link :)

P.S. I know storing images in db isn't really such a great idea as it seems but I decided to do it because I have a tight deadline on this project and I didn't know enough about doing it the filesystem way and thought that I will save some time with db approach. I certainly didn't save any time :)

Comment: I think your problem is elsewhere. `var_dump($img)` should produce a resource. Then, you can use fpassthru($img) to output it. You're probably just confused in the complexity of your script. Make a new empty php script with no other code/framework involved. The art of debugging is the art of ripping everything down to bare bones and testing all of your assumptions. Good luck.

Comment: `var_dump($img)` returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in PDO handling of LOB's: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40913.
The bug is still pending at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with your advice and do the following:

First attempt:
When you save the image in the database to convert it to hex using **base64_encode**. To display just do the opposite using **base64_decode** before generating the image.

If that fails, you can try the following: Open your files. "PHP" in [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++), go to **Format -> convertes to UTF-8 (without BOM)**

For some reason, formatting files with UTF-8 (with BOM) generate invalid characters.

Comment: base64 encoding/decoding everything just because you've got a difficult bug is not a great idea.